# Flashlight turns off on trigger but not back on when exiting trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't really understand this?

What seems to happen is when I enter the trigger zone the flashlight turns off, but when exiting the trigger zone the flashlight doesn't turn on again.  If i reverse the effect i.e  the flash light is off when the scene starts and then when entering the trigger zone the flashlight doesn't turn?  This is the same (minor changes with name) script I used for the main room light (which works)

So with the below code the flashlight is off and i would like to turn it on when entering the trigger zone?

```
public class TurnFlashLightOn : MonoBehaviour
{

void Start()
{

    GameObject[] allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("flashLight");

    foreach (GameObject i in allLights)
    {
        i.SetActive(true);
    }

}
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    GameObject[] allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("flashLight");

    foreach (GameObject i in allLights)
    {
        i.SetActive(false);


    }

}
void OnTriggerExit()
{
    GameObject[] allLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("flashLight");

    foreach (GameObject i in allLights)
    {
        i.SetActive(true);


      }

   }
 }
```

Any ideas why it would switch off but not on?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on `OnTriggerExit` method, to check if the method is called?

Answer (score 1):

Subtle but important detail: `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` only searches through active objects. Once you turn off a flashlight, it won't show up in that search anymore.

You'll need to cache a list of flashlight objects.

If the list is never going to change (you never create or destroy flashlights), then you can populate the list once during `Start`, then refer to the list any time you need it.

If the list is dynamic, you could start with an empty list, then add any flashlight to the list as it gets deactivated. When it's time to turn lights back on, activate every light in the list and then clear the list.

There are plenty of ways you could do this; the basic issue is just that you need some other way to keep track of those inactive objects.

Comment: Okay, i think i understand?  Is there an example which i can look at to understand better?  Thanks

Comment: just use a List<> dude.  it's basic programming.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and what you are telling me, You have an event for when an object passes a threshold the lights will turn off. This threshold contains the Event OnTriggerEnter();

The Threshold or Zone() cannot contain two triggers at once and know which one it is supposed to fire. I can only propose you have an If-Else statement which helps define the logic to which trigger should fire. for instance
 (This is Pseudo Code)

```
  If (EnteringZoneFromStart() = true)
      {OnTriggerEnter()}
  Else If (ExitingZone() = true)
      {OnTriggerExit()}
  Else 
      {OnTriggerEnter()}
```